# Why is an ng-if attribute setting its element's opacity to 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following angular in my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DocTableCtrl as docTableCtrl" ng-init='docTableCtrl.init()'>
    {{docTableCtrl.skuArr.length > 0}}
    <div class="table-wrapper" ng-if="docTableCtrl.skuArr.length > 0">
            made it in
    </div>
</div>
```

At no point in the docTableCtrl object does any instance of "opacity" exist, so the problem does not lie there.

Here is the issue that I'm seeing.  With the code above, `docTableCtrl.skuArr.length > 0` prints out `true`, so I know the ng-if should be showing the element.  Furthermore, looking at the DOM, `table-wrapper` is properly being displayed on the DOM.  However, for some reason in the style attribute, there is an `opacity: 0;` there.  I have no idea where this comes from.  If I remove the `ng-if` from the table-wrapper div, then the opacity no longer gets set to zero and `made it in` is visible on the screen.

This leads me to believe that somehow angular is setting the div's opacity to zero, but I have no clue how or why this is happening.

[image: behavior chart]

Why is the opacity being set to 0 only when the ng-if is present on the `table-wrapper` div?

Comment: Could you share your CSS?

Comment: Do you have ng-animate included in your project? That sometimes manipulates the opacity for transitions.

Comment: @Chic I do have an ng-animate in the project.  I know very little about it, though.  I don't control that part of the code.

Comment: When you inspect the element in most browsers, they have a "Computed" tab where you can look and see what line of CSS is changing what property.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a style rule somewhere setting the opacity. When you inspect an element it should tell you where it is getting the style from. This shot says js:7 since it's getting the style from the code editor. If it was from a style sheet it would say something like site.css:7

[image: Screen cap of developer console]

```js
angular.module('MyApp',[]).
  controller('DocTableCtrl',[function(){
    var docTableCtrl = this;
    
    docTableCtrl.skuArr = [];
    
    docTableCtrl.enqueue = function(){
      docTableCtrl.skuArr.push(""); 
     }
    docTableCtrl.dequeue = function(){
      docTableCtrl.skuArr.pop();
    }
  
  }]);
```

```css
.table-wrapper{
    opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="DocTableCtrl as docTableCtrl" ng-init='docTableCtrl.init()'>
     {{docTableCtrl.skuArr.length}}
    {{docTableCtrl.skuArr.length > 0}}
    <div class="table-wrapper" ng-if="docTableCtrl.skuArr.length > 0">
            made it in
    </div>
  <button ng-click="docTableCtrl.enqueue('')">Enqueue</button>
  <button ng-click="docTableCtrl.dequeue()">Dequeue</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So that was my first thought as well, but when I inspect the element the opacity: 0 is attached to element.style, implying that it is either directly in the HTML, or being injected by javascript.  Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: Correct. It's definitely not ng-if modifying the style attribute.